# How can I create a motion blur effect by using canvas and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a virtual canvas with a drawn icon. This icon is dynamic so I can't make a motion blurred variant of this icon in Photoshop. I render this icon on the scene by this code:

```
function render (context) {
    context.drawImage(this.bufferedIcon, 0, 0);
}
```

Could you tell me if there is a simple way for creating the motion blur of this icon?

Comment: What about using an overlaid element an turning the opacity of it down? You would just have to create some element that when the opacity is changed it makes it look as if it is blurred

Comment: I think that it won't help. I have to get a motion blur of icon. Because I have to imitate that icon is moving very fast. I also found algorithm for Gaussian blur, but I can't find a simple algorithm for motion blur.(

Comment: can you show what you have for Gaussian blur? as well as some fiddle for us to experiment with?

Comment: Sure! But I can't do it right now. I'll prepare a good example and post it here tomorrow.

Comment: 7 years passed and I still didn't provide a good example! Hope you were not upset! :-D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do a simple motion blur use the globalAlpha

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("can").getContext("2d");


// dx and dy is the direction and speed of the blur
function drawBlured(x,y,dx,dy){ // x,y current position, dx,dy delta x,y 
     var samples = 10;  // the number of samples. The greater the number the 
                       // better the effect but the slower the render
                       // over 100 samples and the dynamic range of colours 
                       // will begin to make it look bad
     dx /= samples;   // divide the speed by the number of samples
     dy /= samples;
     ctx.globalAlpha = 1/(samples/1.2);  // set the global alpha need to up the 
                                       // val a bit or it gets to dark
     for(var i = 0; i < samples; i++){  // draw  the image for each sample
         ctx.drawImage(image, x+i*dx,y+i*dy); // moving it as we go
     }
     ctx.globalAlpha = 1;  // restore alpha
} // done;


// code from here down is just for the snippet
var posX= 200;
var posY = 200;
var speedX,speedY
var destX,destY;

// create somthing to blur
var image = document.createElement("canvas");
image.width = 100;
image.height =100;
var ctxS = image.getContext("2d");
ctxS.fillStyle = "Black";
ctxS.beginPath();
ctxS.arc(50,50,48,0,Math.PI*2);
ctxS.fill();

ctxS.beginPath();
ctxS.fillStyle = "#FF0";
ctxS.arc(48,48,44,0,Math.PI*2);
ctxS.fill();

ctxS.fillStyle = "Black";
ctxS.beginPath();
ctxS.arc(25,25,20,0,Math.PI*2);
ctxS.fill();
ctxS.beginPath();
ctxS.arc(75,25,20,0,Math.PI*2);
ctxS.fill();
ctxS.beginPath();
ctxS.arc(50,80,10,0,Math.PI*2);
ctxS.fill();

ctxS.beginPath();
ctxS.fillStyle = "white";
ctxS.arc(25,25,16,0,Math.PI*2);
ctxS.fill();
ctxS.beginPath();
ctxS.arc(75,25,16,0,Math.PI*2);
ctxS.fill();

ctxS.beginPath();
ctxS.fillStyle = "black";
ctxS.arc(25,25,8,0,Math.PI*2);
ctxS.fill();
ctxS.beginPath();
ctxS.arc(75,25,8,0,Math.PI*2);
ctxS.fill();


var moving = false; // when moving
var wait = 10;  // a pause timer
function update(){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,400,400);  // clear
  if(moving){  // draw moving
    drawBlured(posX,posY,speedX,speedY);
    posX += speedX;
    posY += speedY;
    wait -= 1;
    if(wait <= 0){ // done moving pause
      moving = false;
      wait = Math.random()*10+5;
    }
  }else{
    if(wait > 0){  // wait 
      wait -= 1;
      ctx.drawImage(image,posX,posY);

    }else{ // done waiting find a spot to move
      destX = (Math.random()*300)+50;
      destY = (Math.random()*300)+50;        
      speedX = (destX-posX)/5;
      speedY = (destY-posY)/5;        
      ctx.drawImage(image,posX,posY);
      wait = 5;
      moving = true;   // start movng

    }
  }
  setTimeout(update,50);  // do this 20 times a second
}
update();
```

```css
.canC {
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
 }
```

```html
<canvas class="canC" id="can" width=400 height=400></canvas>
```

And don't use the filters for blur. They are mind numbingly inefficient, it may look good on your PC but on many machines it will die and look bad.

Comment: Fantastic answer! Thank you very much!

Comment: Upvote for good answer. I'd rather see requestAnimationFrame as the loop.

Comment: There is a problem with adding motion blur at frame rates higher 30frames a second, you just do not see the effect, The 20FPS is deliberate so that the blur can be seen.